# Troubles remote debugging a .Net Application "no symbols have been loaded for this document."

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a .Net application. I copied it (and the .pdb) to a VM. I am able to attach to the process, but my breakpoints are disabled after attach with:

"The break point currently will not be hit , no symbols have been loaded for this document."

I am sure the PDB on the VM is the right one. I tried adding the PDB path on my main machine to visual studio's symbols path. 
what am I missing?

(Win7 x86, Visual studio 10, .Net 4)

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem was that the PDB files have to be placed at the same folder both on the VM and the host.

Comment: Thank you so much. Then Is not possible to do remote debugging without create the same path? I don't want to believe it.

Comment: Wow this is madness! How did you come across this? I haven't spotted this documented anywhere else!

Answer (score 12):

I had similar issue and I did the following:
Debug=>Options=>General => Remove the check mark for "Enable Just My Code"
This worked for me..

Reference:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/114735/view.html

Answer (score 5):

Another potential cause of the problem is a version mismatch between the code running on the server and the local code. I was able to fix this by redeploying the local code to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I answered the same question posed by another SO user

The answer is very long and tortuous so I won't paste it here.

Go to:

[Symbols not loading for remote debugging on ASP.Net app built and deployed from Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760764/symbols-not-loading-for-remote-debugging-on-asp-net-app-built-and-deployed-from/64170323#64170323)

For the detailed explanation